# LED stays lit when using IC

Tags: logic-gates

I made a simple circuit with a CD4081 IC (2-input AND gates), a DIP switch, and an LED.

The dip switch is set to 00 but the LED will light up regardless. The output from pin 3 on the IC appears to always be 1 or high.

[image]

Both inputs are pulled to negative with an 18k resistor each.

I agree that a decoupling capacitor should be used - but as the cicuit is static I would not expect this to be the problem.

The supply voltage is [**INSERT SUPPLY VOLTAGE HERE!!!**]

Comment: connect all the unused inputs to VSS or VDD. a resistor in series with the LED wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Are your resistors in the correct sockets? It's hard to see but it looks a bit like you have one lead in the wrong position (pin 1 ?).  Including your schematic would help.

Comment: The resistors are in the correct sockets.

Comment: [connect all [inputs to valid logic levels\]](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/676863/led-stays-lit-when-using-ic#comment1802379_676863) and add a decoupling capacitor between the power supply pins with low wiring inductance.

Comment: No schematic + no bypass capacitors = no way to help ;)

Comment: We can only guess. Maybe the chip is damaged because of the things mentioned already what is wrong with the circuit, or because LED has no current limiting so chip output can be damaged to overcurrent. The supply voltage is also unknown.

Comment: The left hand 18k APPEARS to be plugged into the column to the left of pin 1 . Is it ? It should still work. || The LED needs a series R. The IC MAY be damaged, but I'd expect not. || Use a meter or oscilloscope to see if IC pin 7 is actually at ground potential - IF the green link was not making contact the IC would float. || You should state Vdd, and anything else lible to be possibly relevant. || A supply decoupling capacitor is always a good idea BUT it should still work. || Add a ground wire t least one input on the other 3 gates. This is not liable to be the issues, bvut may be.

Answer (score 0):

The left hand 18k APPEARS to be plugged into the column to the left of pin 1 .
Is it ?
It should still work, as the AND gate needs both inputs high to give a high out.

The LED needs a series R.
The CD4081 [datasheet here](https://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=10&gotoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fcd4073b) is rated for a few mA from output-high at most likely supply voltages.
The LED appears to be drawing far more  than rated current.
Supply voltage needs to be known to allow a suitable series R to be calculated.

The IC **MAY** be damaged due to overload.

Use a meter or oscilloscope to see if IC pin 7 is actually at ground potential - IF the green link was not making contact the IC would float.
This MAY result in the LED staying on.

You should state Vdd, and anything else liable to be possibly relevant.

A supply decoupling capacitor is always a good idea BUT it should still work without one.

Add a ground wire to least one input and preferably both inputs on the other 3 gates.
This is not liable to be the issues, but may be.